# Does the 'Engi Virus' have side effects?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've encountered a spaceship that stated that I have a virus.

I've sent an Engi to talk with them, he disappeared, we had a fight.
After the fight he returned 'improved':
[image]

It looks to good to be true, so - is there a catch later on? or is it part of a quest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope - no catch, at this point he's just a regular crew member (albeit a very skilled one.) He will behave as any other Engi crew would, and will stay with you until your victory / demise.

Source: [FTL Wikia](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/The_Engi_Virus), personal gameplay

Comment: So I assume that nothing happens if he dies, or traded also, right?

Comment: @ShlomiOhayon Besides losing the best crewmember you'll ever have, no.

Comment: It may interest you to learn that he is not the only super-skilled crewmember that you can get as a reward: http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Special_Event_Crew_Members